# How do I use the correct DbContext in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

So I am working on one tiny project for a client that requires it to be in VB.NET.  Using the code first method, I created some models using the default constructor for each class, so I ended up with 8 different connection strings in the web.config.

I changed all of the constructors to use DefaultConnection and removed the previous migration data, but I seem to be unable to get it to work now.

When I run `Enable-Migrations` I get the following error:

`More than one context type was found in the assembly 'QuickTest'. To enable migrations for 'QuickTest.Bro', use Enable-Migrations
-ContextTypeName QuickTest.Bro.`

I understand that it is telling me I have two different DbContexts and I need to select one. However, I did not intentionally create the second one, I want to use the default. Where is the definition of the 2nd one, how do I remove it, and what do I need to do to consolidate?

Here is my class:

```
<Table("Bros")>
Public Class Bro
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Overridable Property Bros As DbSet(Of Bro)

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=DefaultConnection")
    End Sub

    <Key>
    <Column("ID", Order:=1)>
    <DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)>
    <Required>
    Public Property Id As Long

    <Required>
    Public Property Version As Long

    ' TODO: Add relationship to user2
    <Required>
    Public Property User1 As User

    ' TODO: Add relationship to user1
    <Required>
    Public Property User2 As User

End Class
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Looking at this code, it's pretty clear you are new to Entity Framework. I suggest you go run through a tutorial before continuing here.

Comment: "...I ended up with 8 different connection strings in the web.config".  Then you did it wrong.  If you do it right, you end up with one connection string and one DbContext.

Comment: Looks like your mixing your context and models into one class. You should have a POCO class for each entity and a single dbcontext with a dbset for each table. See here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/vb/adding-a-model

Comment: Thank you @SteveGreene for actually helping, it's getting hard to find resources specifically for vb.net. Your link did help. I have about 12 tabs open and not one of them states that I need a separate POCO for the dbcontext.